# How to select button inside of multiple classes with selenium python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a page with multiple elements, it's called cards, and on this page I want to click a button on some cards but not on all. The problem is the structure of individual cards because only class of card is different but class inside of cards and button are the same. I'm not sure how to find a right card.

Usually I use something like this, but in this case i want to select certain cards.

```
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'button-class').click()
```

But in this case I have something like this...

```
<div id="card-summer_1">
    <div class="card_card">
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button-class">
            <button class="button-share">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="card-summer_2">
    <div class="card_card">
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button-class">
            <button class="button-share">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="card-summer_3">
    <div class="card_card">
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button-class">
            <button class="button-share">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to click on button on id `id="card-summer_1"` and `id="card-summer_3"`?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

There are two buttons, I want to click on a class `button-class`.

Comment: _click on button on id `id="card-summer_1"` and `id="card-summer_3"`_: But click can be invoked on on a single webelement, which specific one do you want to click?

Comment: I want to click on both, I don't want to click on `id="card-summer_2"`, that is why I do it like this.

Comment: Both of the elements can be identified distinctly with `id="card-summer_1"` and `id="card-summer_3"` to click, so what is your question here?

Comment: No they can't, I want to click on button inside of div id `"card-summer_1"` and `"card-summer_3"`. `div`s with this id are different, but every button has same class, so I cannot target the button, and there are two buttons. I hope now it's a bit clearer.

Comment: No, you don't click on multiple objects at the same time using Selenium, you click on each of them one by one.

Comment: Yes, I want to click on one and then on second one. But how to click in my case?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find elements instead by CSS selector:

`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-summer_1 .button-class")`

Comment: It doesn't work when there are two buttons. How to specified button?

Comment: you can instead specify the specific class of the button, I've edited my answer for clarity

Answer (score 1):

By XPATH:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='card-summer_1']//button"]).click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='card-summer_3']//button"]).click()
```

By CSS_SELECTOR:

```
driver.find_element(By.By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-summer_1 button").click()
driver.find_element(By.By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-summer_3 button").click()
```

Comment: It doesn't work when there are two buttons. How to specified button?